# Tracking buttons on facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to track the buttons clicks on facebook messenger bot. Does any one have any experience or tips on doing it.
Here is a portion of my JSON

```
buttons:[ 
{ 
type:'web_url',
url:'<link to my url>',
title:'Click me'
},
{ 
type:'phone_number',
title:'Call',
payload:'+1' + phoneNumber
}
]
```

I am primarily unable to track the phone_number, I can get away with few workarounds with the web_url on the target side.

Answer (score 0):

Change the call me one to be a URL then on your website note that they clicked the button and redirect them to tel:+123456789012345